# Android Calling API using Remote Server IP Address - Connection Refused

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Due to some other issues at the moment I'm having to use my remote API server IP address instead of our domain.

I have a console application that uses the exact API client code from the Xamarin Forms application. I can run this console test harness and call the API without any issues.

But when I run the same API client code on an Android device or the Google emulator the connection is refused.

Not sure what to try to get it working.  Is this an Android policy of not allowing IP address hosts?

How could I whitelist our IP address if this is the case?

Any advice would be great.

**UPDATE**

I just added a controller to the API that returns "hello".  I redeployed the service and I can browse to this endpoint using the browser on the device and the emulator.

Comment: "Connection refused" is a server issue, not a client.  You might try looking at the HTTP stack settings in the Android project "Android Build" panel.

Comment: Yeah it is a server thing but if the server had an issue it wouldn't respond to the test harness either.  Very confusing.

Comment: a request coming from two different clients using the same code might still have differences in their request signatures based on the platform.  You might have to compare the two requests with a packet sniffer

Comment: @Jason Also I'm not sure what you mean by HTTP stack settings. I can't see anything related to that.

Comment: Hmm ... this app has been running for months. The only difference is that I'm currently having to use the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while back. An app was running for over a year and suddenly it stopped working after updating the server. The fix for me was setting the `HttpClient implementation` to 'Android'. The default configuration couldn't set up a safe connection.

```
Projectname.Android
-> Properties
-> Android Options
-> Advanced
-> HttpClient implementation - Android
```